# FireDac connection does not perform commit

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, firedac, post-commit, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I am trying to convert a project from Delphi XE8 to Delphi 10.2 Tokyo, having some trouble with autocommit:
Building with XE8: every time a 'Post' is performed, the update is committed to the DB automatically.
Building with 10.2: the updates remain in the current transaction. it needs a 'commitRetaining' to let updates be applied.

It is the same project, so same source code and same properties. Unique difference is the 'Connection.UpdateOptions.AutoComitUpdate' property, which is only in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo, and set to true.

What difference is there between these two version of FD components and why it does not autocommit? How to solve it?

Comment: Which database back-end?

Comment: FireBird DB back-end

Comment: `AutoCommitUpdates` is related to cached updates, not transactions. Transaction auto commit is driven by the `AutoCommit` option. What you describe sounds like you're caching updates though. Could we have a minimal compilable example (including settings that you have on your FireDAC objects), please?

Comment: AutoCommit is set to true too. Anyway, I'm discovering that the issue is not related with connection and transaction components.. it's something else that i don't even know what is and where happens... I will have to look for all the source code in datamodules. Thank you, question can be closed.